# Implementing Viewing.Extension.Transform extension of autodesk forge viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Are we implementing this code by ourself, or loading the extension just like that for extension of markup or first-person view.
Is there a easier way to implement this extension?

Comment: I might not be understanding well on your question. Are you looking for how to create an extension?Or you wanted to build a code with the same abilities of markup or first-person of Forge Viewer? While these two features are extension already. Could you elaborate on your specific requirement?

Comment: i want to use Viewing.Extension.Transform extension of https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs ,in my system. without the having to add that code manually, is there a way to use it as methods of extension just like that of markup

Comment: This is a tool our colleague produced. It is not a built-in functionalities. So without importing the code, this tool will not be available with Forge Viewer. Did you hit any problem to add this module? probably you have done so: the demo code is written in ES6 and its default config of Webpack outputs all modules. we could change the config and output Transform module only. Finally load these output dataset to the project.